# How to downgrade from Chrome 35 to 34 without losing data?

Tags: google-chrome, migration, chromium, downgrade

After upgrading Chromium from 34 to 35, the usability of Chromium went downhill. So I decided to downgrade Chromium. Fortunately, the previous version of Chromium was still somewhere on my disk, so downgrading (in ArchLinux) was as simple as:

```
sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/chromium-34.0.1847.137-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

After running the previous command, Chromium did start, but unfortunately, I kept getting bugged by the following message on start-up:

> Your profile can not be used because it is from a newer version of Google Chrome. Some features may be unavailable. Please specify a different profile directory or use a newer version of Chrome.

One way to get rid of this message is to delete `~/.config/chromium/Default/Web Data`, but this also caused my **search engine keywords to disappear**.

How can I downgrade Chromium without losing any data?

<sup>Note: I'm using Linux, but this problem is platform-independent. Feel free to answer from the perspective of a non-Linux operating system such as Windows.</sup>

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. Do you really want to run an outdated browser version forever now? This has quite a few security implications.

Comment: @slhck No, just until the UX bugs are fixed. After upgrading, I got random visual artifacts, bad font rendering in the UI, random black rectangles, and dragging bugs (http://crbug.com/376761). This is even worse than the JavaScript and devtools bugs in Chromium 33 (which I skipped as well). If the bug doesn't get resolved within two release cycles, I will run my own compiled version of Chromium with Aura disabled.

Comment: In the future, you might find this is a lot easier, if you make a backup of your system/data before you upgrade.

Comment: Yeah, because it's practical to backup your whole system and all your data every few hours when Google releases a new version… well, maybe if you're Google. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note: Close Chrome and back up your profile before messing with it!**

`Web Data` is a SQLite database, so I used the [sqlite3 program](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) to open the database.

1. What is the current version of the "Web Data" database? (run `SELECT * from meta;`)

   ```
   sqlite> SELECT * FROM meta;
   Default Search Provider ID|34
   last_compatible_version|55
   version|55
   Builtin Keyword Version|70
   ```
2. The emphasized rows in the previous output refer to internal database version numbers in Chromium. For every version, you can find the relevant migration codes in [Chromium's source code (autofill_table.cc)](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/components/autofill/core/browser/webdata/autofill_table.cc). Specifically, take a look at the [`AutofillTable::MigrateToVersion`](http://cs.chromium.org/%22AutofillTable::MigrateToVersion%28%22) method. Since my database version is 55, I looked at ["case 55"](http://cs.chromium.org/file:autofill_table.cc)

   ```
   case 55:
         *update_compatible_version = true;
         return MigrateToVersion55MergeAutofillDatesTable();
   ```

   After finding out this method, I was almost ready to write a SQLite query to reverse the migration.
3. Using the knowledge from the previous step (and the original schema from a different table on another computer), I constructed the following query (copy-paste the query to `sqlite3`):
   **Note: This query is specific to downgrading Chrome 35 to 34!**

   ```
   CREATE TABLE autofill_v54 (
       name VARCHAR,
       value VARCHAR,
       value_lower VARCHAR,
       pair_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
       count INTEGER DEFAULT 1);
   CREATE TABLE autofill_dates (
       pair_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
       date_created INTEGER DEFAULT 0);        

   INSERT INTO autofill_v54 (
       name,
       value,
       value_lower,
       count
   ) SELECT name, value, value_lower, count FROM autofill;

   INSERT INTO autofill_dates (
       pair_id,
       date_created
   ) SELECT pair_id, date_created
     FROM autofill_v54 a54 JOIN autofill a USING (name, value);

   DROP TABLE autofill;
   ALTER TABLE autofill_v54 RENAME TO autofill;

   CREATE INDEX autofill_name ON autofill (name);
   CREATE INDEX autofill_name_value_lower ON autofill (name, value_lower);
   ```
4. After reverting the migration, you can safely lower the database version:

   ```
   UPDATE meta SET value='54' WHERE key='version' OR
                                    key = 'last_compatible_version';
   ```
5. Close the database using `.quit`

After completing all of these steps, I started Chromium, there were no annoying popups and all profile data was still intact!

Comment: Actually, it works from newer versions of chrome too, it will recreate the version 54, which was used in chrome 34 and then re-update to the newer version; of course, it is likely to quit at some point, and may not fix everything, but it does get rid of the popups.  (reverted from version 40 to 33.0.1750 to get flash drm working)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm: the solution with sqlite3 works fine !

I'm an Ubuntu user (14.04), but I tried this method not with chromium but with google-chrome-stable.

I've downgraded chrome from 35 to 34 because there is no way for running java applet in the release 35. :-(

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list*
sudo apt-get update
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://95.31.35.30/chrome/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_34.0.1847.137-1_amd64.deb
```

By removing this source, google-chrome will no longer update automatically.
I have installed the release 34 from nautilus with gdebi. You can install gdebi with:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

The problem starts here... Message = 'Your profile can not be used because it is from a newer...'
You can install sqlite3 like this:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

to execute the solution above (provided by Rob W), do:

```
cd ~/.config/google-chrome/Default
sqlite3 Web\ Data
```

After that, simply copy/paste the steps 1, 3, 4, 5 given by Rob W.
Hope this help.  ;-)